# Photoshop action for changing text number and saving with variable

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a lot of graphic buttons that I need to make. I have 2 layers

1. TEXT (This is going to be numbers 1-48 for instance)
2. White Button image

I'm not sure how to go about writing this action or if I need a script. I need to have the text layer start at 1 and follow this progression.

1. save file w1.png (this yields a png with a button labeled with a "1"
2. change text to 2
3. save file w2.png (this yields a png with a button labeled with a "2"
4. change text to 3
5. . . . .

ect. . .all the way to 48. So this would make 48 images automatically. Can this be done with "actions" or do I need to learn scripting?

Save

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a script for this, but it's going to be a rather simple one

```
function main() {

//this just checks if you have a text layer selected
try {
    var textLayer = activeDocument.activeLayer.textItem
} catch (e) {
    alert("active layer isn't a text layer");
    return
};

var loops = 48,
    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(),
    outputFolder = Folder.selectDialog('', Folder.desktop); //this will ask for an output folder

for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    var myNum = i + 1;
    textLayer.contents = myNum; //this will change layer contents to number only. if you need some text here, write it in quotes like textLayer.contents = "my text" + myNum;
    activeDocument.saveAs(new File(outputFolder + "/w" + myNum + ".png"), pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}

}
app.activeDocument.suspendHistory("temp", "main()");
```

Comment: Wow, this is gold! Worked perfectly!

Comment: where to apply this function ? can you please explain I am in need of this ?

Comment: @VivekRahul sorry, I didn't understand your question

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Actually I dont know how to run this function then I found out !

Comment: @VivekRahul ah welp https://www.google.fr/search?q=how+to+run+photoshop+scripts&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-fr&client=safari